# Webpack 4: Conditionally enabling PostCSS plugins

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-4, postcss

I've integrated PostCSS into Webpack, using a separate `postcss.config.js` file.

I want to enable `cssnano` when doing production builds, and disable it for development builds. How can I do this?

Here is my **webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');

const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env, argv) =>
{
    //const isProduction = (process.env.WEBPACK_MODE === 'production')
    const isProduction = argv.mode === 'production' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

    const config = {
        entry: './src/index.js',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
            chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].js'
        },
        devtool: 'source-map',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                    use: [
                        // fallback to style-loader in development
                        //process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        {
                            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        },
                        //'css-loader?-url',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                minimize: true,
                                sourceMap: true,
                                url: false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                debug: false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                outputStyle: 'compressed',
                                sourceMapContents: false
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },

        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist', {
                watch: true
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
                // both options are optional
                filename: isProduction ? "live.[contenthash].css" : "live.css",
                chunkFilename: "[name].[contenthash].css"
            }),
            new ManifestPlugin()
        ]
    }

    return config;
}
```

Here is my **postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('postcss-url'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
        require('cssnano')({
            preset: 'default',
        })
    ]
}
```

Secondly, is a separate `postcss.config.js` recommended? I see some examples where the PostCSS plugins are defined in `webpack.config.js`, and others where it's all done in the separate file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **`postcss.config.js`** you can do [checking for the environment property](https://github.com/michael-ciniawsky/postcss-load-config#array):

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import')(),
    require('postcss-url')(),
    require('autoprefixer')(),
    env === 'production' ? require('cssnano')({preset: 'default' })() : false,
  ]
})
```

Comment: what do you suggest if i want to add check which checks if VueJs global state contains value this then do this else do this etc

Comment: looks like webpack plugins array cannot contain boolean values:
```ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.plugins[0] should be one of these:
   object { apply, … } | function```

Comment: @Titenis I think it depends on the version. The original answer was written 2 years ago, something could change in the latest versions.

Answer (score 4):

### Option 1. Use webpack merge

With [webpack-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge), you can create conditional configurations based on the `NODE_ENV` and merge them in one single configuration at execution time, the advantage is that you don't create duplication of code and everything can be done in one file, the only disadvantage is using a new package.

```
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV

let Config = {

  //Other shared configurations by production and development

  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'public', to: 'public' },
    ])
  ]

}

if (ENV === 'production') {
  Config = merge(Config, {
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "public/styles.css"
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
        cssProcessor: cssnano,
        cssProcessorOptions: {
          parser: safe,
          discardComments: { removeAll: true }
        }
      })
    ],
    mode: 'production'
  })
}

if (ENV === 'development') {
  Config = merge(Config, {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
      new StyleLintPlugin(
        {
          emitErrors: false,
          configFile: '.stylelintrc',
          context: 'src',
          files: '**/*.pcss',
        },
      ),
    ]
  })
}

const WebpackConfig = Config
```

### Option 2. Use different configurations

Two separated files `webpack.config.prod.js` and `webpack.config.dev.js` can be created and call them with different npm scripts. The problem with this solution is that there is a duplication of code.

Comment: ...Or, you create also a `webpack.config.base.js` file which contains the common code and then you import it from the `webpack.config.dev.js` and the `webpack.config.prod.js`. In this way you have granular control on all the aspects and still do not install additional packages that might result redundant.

Comment: The solution provided by @Adriano is also valid, my only worry about his solution was to replicate the functionality of the package `webpack-merge` but this gist makes a quite easy solution to do it. https://gist.github.com/ericclemmons/40a2783313d157d8b448

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not seeing how this changes which PostCSS plugins are loaded, as `postcss.config.js` is not affected by merging Webpack configs?

Comment: @PeterB `postcss.config.js` should load your plugins and on the webpack configuration files you should select conditionally how they are used, In my example, you can see that `cssnano` is only used for production.